# Running custom script after azure container service deployment using swarm

Tags: azure, docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I want to run a custom script after a swarm cluster is ready. I'm using following template to create azure container service (swarm based). https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/875d139c16c9c023dce519e6dd48c707e3473346/101-acs-swarm

I couldn't find a way to run custom script automatically after the deployment finishes.

Comment: Or is there any way to install docker image via azure template on acs-swarm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to run a custom script on the VMs inside the acs cluster. The only workaround for automation is to bring your own swarm cluster and run the custom script to install your software.

Ref: https://github.com/phagunbaya/azure-templates/tree/master/docker-swarm

Comment: The user has full access to the VMs created in an ACS cluster. It is trivial to write a script to execute on each of these VMs. http://github.com/rgardler/acs-cli does just this.

Comment: @rgardler For the acs cluster (swarm) available in the azure marketplace uses VM scale sets. And I couldn't find any way to ssh to them nor a way to run script via azure template. In such constraints, I had to end up creating manual cluster.

I'm also aware of the new changes that are coming in for ACS to use availability sets instead of scale sets.

Comment: The documentation for the GitHub quickstarts contain the following:

"a set of agents in a VM scale set (VMSS). The agent VMs can be accessed through a master. See agent forwarding for an example of how to do this." with a link to https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-acs-mesos/docs/SSHKeyManagement.md#key-management-and-agent-forwarding-with-windows-pageant (if you are using Mac or Linux just add '-A' to enable agent forwarding).

I'm not sure what changes you are referring to with respect to availability sets. There are no plans to move away from scale sets.